# Table view not Showing Data from Parse.com

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa, parse-platform

In my view controller I just added a TableView .
I entered all the delegates in file.h both file.m .
The identifications of the cell has been entered correctly even in the storyboard and the custom cell was connected to the cell ch custom class I created.

Now I put this code (use Parse.com) do not get any kind of error, the code always super clean, but when I go to make the Run the table does not show me any data, as if it were connected to the cell or as a custom class if there was no reuse identifier, instead both steps have been made ... I do not understand why I can not see anything ... Can you figure out what is the error?

```
# import " FFFriendInAttesa.h "
# import " FFCustomCellFriendInAttesa.h "

@ interface FFFriendInAttesa ()    
@ end    
@ implementation FFFriendInAttesa


- (Void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad ] ;
    self.FFTableView.delegate = self ;
    self.FFTableView.dataSource = self ;
    [self QueryForTableView ] ;
}


- ( NSInteger ) numberOfSectionsInTableView : ( UITableView * ) tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- ( NSInteger ) tableView : ( UITableView * ) tableView numberOfRowsInSection : ( NSInteger ) section {
    return [ self.UtentiInAttesa count] ;       
     }

- (void) { QueryForTableView
    
    PFQuery QueryForUserClass * = [ PFUser query ] ;
    [ QueryForUserClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * objects , NSError * error ) {
        if ( error) {
            self.UtentiInAttesa = objects ;
            NSLog ( @ " start query : % @ " , self.UtentiInAttesa ) ;
        }
    } ] ;
    [ self.FFTableView reloadData ] ;
}


- ( UITableViewCell * ) tableView : ( UITableView * ) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath : ( NSIndexPath * ) indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @ " CellaAmici " ;
    FFCustomCellFriendInAttesa * cell = [ self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier : CellIdentifier forIndexPath : indexPath ] ;
    if ( cell) {
        cell = [ [ FFCustomCellFriendInAttesa alloc ] initWithStyle : UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier : @ " CellaAmici "] ;
    }
        PFObject * user = [ self.UtentiInAttesa objectAtIndex : indexPath.row ] ;
        cell.FFNomeFriendLabel.text = [user objectForKey : FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME ] ;
          
    return cell ;
}

@ end
```

File.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface FFFriendInAttesa : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *FFTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *UtentiInAttesa;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is your table view refreshed before its data source get updated. you should do like this:

```
- (void)QueryForTableView {
PFQuery QueryForUserClass * = [ PFUser query ] ;
[ QueryForUserClass findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * objects , NSError * error ) {
    // You put a wrong condition, objecs only returned when no error.
    if (!error) {
        self.UtentiInAttesa = objects ;
        NSLog ( @ " start query : % @ " , self.UtentiInAttesa ) ;
        // Refresh your tableview here
         [ self.FFTableView reloadData ] ;
    }
} ] ;

}
```

Comment: Hello: D .. I'm not using a PfQueryTableViewController but a simple UIViewController.
The query I'm doing it with - (PFQuery *) but with a - (void) and when I insert the code you suggested I return error

void method not return value

Among other things in that query I will also call MatchesQuery that's why I left it so ... Now I do not know what am I doing wrong at this point ... : (

Comment: oh, my bad, I found your error. you should reload your table when your query complete. because you query the result in background, hence, the tableview is reloaded before its datasource get updated. look up my code above

Comment: Do you believe me if I tell you that even with this change the TableView remains white?? is an incredible situation! never happened ... I connected everything, it seems as if the table view does not recognize the cell to insert the data but as I said is the identifier that the custom classes of the cell are inserted correctly even in the storyboard ... I can not understand ... The funny thing is that I also tried to delete the files and the view controller and do it all over again but I did not get any results, the situation is still the same ...

Comment: @rory, pls look over my code again, I see another prob that your tableview not loaded is you put your code in wrong condition. `if (error)` should be changed to `if (!error)`. because if error occured, there is no way you got the returned objects. Does it make sense?

Comment: My God, now I'm totally stoned! after 4 months I'm here every day before I went out of my head and I'm lost for this stupid situation! Babygau you have my permission to kill me! : D

Comment: hihi, it happens to everyone in every way. so no blood is splashed over here :-P. We're here to learn and help each other. I'm happy to help you ;)

Comment: heheh it certainly is and I'm glad to help. Maybe the attention could avoid making mistakes so stupid and lose a lot of time: (  You deserve another nice +1

Comment: Tks @rory, I'm glad you sorted it out :)

Comment: Do not kill me but since you sent me ahead now I stumbled upon another trap ahahahah ... Tell me if you can find the error here because in another view controller I worked, not here ... Maybe I'm a little tired ahahahah    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579716/retrieve-image-for-different-class-data-browser-parse-com