# Retrieve Image for different Class Data browser Parse.com

Tags: uiimageview, tableview, parse-platform

Hello everyone I'm trying to display the profile picture of a user registered with the app.

In this query I am getting data from a different class from wherever it is in the photo databrowser. I tried with MatchesQuery but I can not find the right combination ... Probably my code is wrong ...

```
- (void)QueryForTableView {


    PFQuery *QueryForFriend=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Amicizie"];
    [QueryForFriend whereKey:@"A_User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [QueryForFriend includeKey:@"Da_User"];

    PFQuery *RetrievePhoto_User = [PFUser query];
[RetrievePhoto_User whereKey:@"photo" matchesQuery:QueryForFriend];

    [QueryForFriend findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"nome:%@", objects);
            self.UtentiInAttesa = objects ;
            [self.FFTableView reloadData];
        }
    }];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellaAmici";
    FFCustomCellFriendInAttesa  *cell = [self.FFTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[FFCustomCellFriendInAttesa alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellaAmici"];
    }

    PFUser *FriendUser = [self.UtentiInAttesa objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *ValueNomeCognome = [[FriendUser objectForKey:@"Da_User"] valueForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];
    cell.FFNomeFriendLabel.text = ValueNomeCognome;


    cell.FFFotoProfiloInAttesa.file = [FriendUser objectForKey:@"photo"];
    cell.FFFotoProfiloInAttesa.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFNoFotoUSer"];

    [cell.FFFotoProfiloInAttesa.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.FFFotoProfiloInAttesa.layer setCornerRadius:22.5f];
    [cell.FFFotoProfiloInAttesa loadInBackground];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `PFQuery *queryFoto = [PFUser query];` this one doesn't make sense, shoud be query your `Photo` class, I'm supposed

Comment: I do not understand then how did you work with the collection view ... I used the exact same code ... I do not understand

Comment: You should name your query more meaningful, otherwise I can't understand what is your query purpose.

Comment: I figured out part of the problem, before I post my answer, I need you to confirm that do you store photo object in `Amicizie class` or `User class`???

Comment: In practice, the data that I need are in Class "Friends" instead of the photo is in the special class _USER that used for user registration.

It 's weird because, I repeat, in collactionView has not given me problems this thing

Comment: is `Amicizie` means `Friends class`? Sorry, I'm not an Italian :-P

Comment: Yes: D Amici = Friends ... I created a custom class called "Amicizie"

Comment: I have not used PFRelation to make friends but a Custom Class: D

Comment: So you only want to find the friends of current user, right? I meant to returned Friends objects, so you can manipulate these object for later use.

Comment: It is practically the table shows all users who have sent a friend request to PFuser Current User so I need photos of the user who submitted the request to the CurrentUser

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39956/discussion-between-babygau-and-rory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little chat with you. The following code is unnecessary and wrong. So simple remove it and you are set:

```
PFQuery *RetrievePhoto_User = [PFUser query];
[RetrievePhoto_User whereKey:@"photo" matchesQuery:QueryForFriend];
```